# htaccess 3 variables rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the below code which works perfectly.

```
# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one (WEB)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+search-menu(?:\.php)?\?r_id=([^\s&]+)&name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /search-menu/%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]
# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one (WEB)
RewriteRule ^search-menu/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ search-menu.php?r_id=$1&name=%2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Now I want to do another that has 3 variables like so;

```
# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one (WEB)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+search-restaurant(?:\.php)?\?location=([^\s&]+)&day=([^\s&]+)&time=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /search-restaurant/%1/%2/%3? [R=302,L,NE]
# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one (WEB)
RewriteRule ^search-restaurant/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ search-restaurant.php?location=$1&day=%2&time=%3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

I'm getting Internal Server Error.
Can someone point out what is wrong please.

Comment: Call parameters? Error.log entries? ...

Comment: None, just 500 error

Comment: Your code looks ok,and there is nothing that can cause 500 error . Do you have any other rules in .htaccss?

Comment: Just a rule that removes `.php` extension site wide